# How to reset all DI services or the DI scope on user logout in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, maui

In my MAUI Blazor app, users can log out at runtime. When they do, I basically want to reset all injected services, so when another user logs in, they get a "fresh" state, avoiding possible errors, inconsitencies and data breach.

This is a problem I thought should be common, but couldn't find an answer for.
So my questions are: is this approach even possible, and if so, how?
And if not, what would be the typical way to solve the problem?

To my understanding, MAUI doesn't really use DI scopes like ASP.NET Core does. So I can't work with scopes here.

Comment: Scopes have nothing to do with ASP.NET Core. Scopes are created in code using IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope. ASP.NET Core creates a scope on every request. Blazor Server creates a scope for every user connection (more specifically, SignalR circuit).

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Blazor is tightly coupled to the DI infrastructure and with this infrastructure, there is only one container instance that is reused. Resetting state is not possible in this container, but even if it would, it would only cause other issues (multi-threading issues). The only solution here is to rigorously test the application to prevent user state to be stored in Singletons or Captive Dependencies.

Comment: Why are your dependencies aware of your user is the question I have right now!

Answer (score 1):

Shell is reusing the views and view models. One approach is to reset the Page and/or DataContext as navigated. Here is an example:

You need some interface with a method to reset the object:

```cs
public interface IResettable
{
    void Reset();
}
```

You could implement this in your views as necessary to reset focus, show the keyboard, etc.

```cs
public partial class SignInPage : IResettable
{
    public void Reset()
    {
        userName.Focus();
    }
}
```

You could implement this in your viewmodels to clear previously loaded data by resetting bound variables.

```cs
public partial class SignInViewModel : ObservableObject, IResettable
{
    public void Reset()
    {
        UserName = null;
        Password = null;
    }
}
```

Finally you need to hook into the Shell navigation to do this automatically during navigation.

```cs
protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigated(args);
    _logger.ShellNavigated(args);

    // Support resetting the View first.
    try
    {
        if (Current.CurrentPage is IResettable resettable)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(resettable.Reset);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.FailedToResetView(ex);
    }

    // Support resetting the BindingContext after the view.
    try
    {
        if (Current.CurrentPage?.BindingContext is IResettable resettableBindingContext)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(resettableBindingContext.Reset);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.FailedToResetBindingContext(ex);
    }
}
```